# Rename zfs disk path

Tags: zfs

FreeBSD zfs 2 disk mirror
I replaced a dead hdd and somehow it renamed  ada0 to ada1

```
zpool status
      mirror-0                DEGRADED     0     0     0
        ada1p3                ONLINE       0     0     0
        13232760139244878088  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/ada1p3


zdb
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 14736635148224059001
                path: '/dev/ada1p3'

            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 13232760139244878088
                path: '/dev/ada1p3'
                phys_path: '/dev/ada1p3'
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the problem.

zpool attach zroot ada1p3 ada0p3

gpart bootcode -b /boot/pmbr -p /boot/gptzfsboot -i 1 ada0